Import "customtkinter" could not be resolved
I am trying to import customtkinter and it's not working at all. I have installed custom tkinter and it even comes up when I do pip list but it keeps saying that customtkinter is not resolved. I've tried almost everything with the resources I could find online but to no success. Would appreciate any help I can get.

As you can see above, I've installed it already.

customtkinter 5.2.2 You need to update.

You're using the python 2.7 version, which is incompatible with 4.0.2 version of customtkinter.

https://pypi.org/project/customtkinter/4.0.2/
I suggest you to upgrade, your packages & your current python version that you are using, because there is no such version package that is compatible with 2.7 python version, the earliest package requirements for python is >= 3.7, so in order to use such library your python must be at least >= 3.7 version.

https://pypi.org/project/customtkinter/0.0.0/
